# How to save detected face in Android using OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

I am using OpenCV's sample code to detect face with android device. I want to save only detected face area to sd card. I am trying to convert mat to Bitmap and save it. But my problem is it saves whole image rather than just Face. here's my method to convert mat to bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mGray.cols(), mGray.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mGray, bitmap);

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
               bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
               out.flush();
               out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
```

I am a beginner with Opencv. Please help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you are never trying to get the face pixels. After you detect face, I suggest you to do something such as:

```
Mat mFaceMatrix = mRgba.submat(facesArray.y, facesArray.y + facesArray.heigth, facesArray.x, facesArray.x + facesArray.width);
```

Now passing this matrix to createBitmap function should do the trick.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mFaceMatrix.cols(), mFaceMatrix.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(mFaceMatrix, bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. I think the problem is with your matrix mGray. It seems that mGray contains the whole image pixels and you are creating bitmap using it. Therefore, my suggestion would be to first check your mGray matrix and take face region and copy the pixels to another matrix and then create bitmap with that new matrix that contains just the face. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I changed code a bit. I changed mat from mGray to mRgba and now I am getting rectangle around the face but still I am getting the whole image. Let me show you another method to draw the rectange.

Comment: I posted my method by answering the que. I could not do by other way.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that there is only one face. We can crop the result of the face detection and save it as described in this python script:

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('c'):
        crop = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w] 
        cv2.imwrite("face.jpg", crop)

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```